# Strategy for mitigating race conditions when updating cookies?

Tags: cookies, race-condition

So the situation is that on a given page there are many HTTP requests and each of these need to update a single shared cookie. There is no possibility to control how many requests are made per page, but realistically there can be 10+.

We've seen issues where only the last http request successfully updates the cookie and I am told this is due to browser dependencies.

Is this a known issue in general and are there any strategies for mitigating the risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strategy is to avoid storing mutable information in the cookie itself, and instead have the cookie be an identifier of some sort that identifies a record in a database of some kind somewhere. Then, your server updates information in the (server-side) database, instead of changing the cookie value.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that but I think it's my only option.

Comment: If the server writes the mutable information to the cookie, wouldn't you end up with the same race condition where multiple different identifiers would be set for the same browser?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of requests are these? The only ones where you don't control the order are things like images, script src, and iframe. And you should not be updating cookies for any of those.

You should be updating the cook in the main page, the one with the HTML source. After that if you have ajax requests you are in control of the order so you should not have a problem there.

Comment: They are snippets of code people can place on their site, for a variety of different functions. Therefore I am not in control of how they are deployed in the code. Why shouldn't I be updating cookies when an image (e.g. a pixel) is called? Ultimately, a bunch of concurrent http requests for things like images (not script) results in the cookies failing due to race conditions. There seems to be no easy solution server side.